# Get response.data and match it in a switch statement

Tags: javascript

I am calling a API which is returning a value. I want to match that value in a switch case. Why is the switch case not working . I have already checked the type.

```
const resultString = String(response.data.body);
if ( resultString === "Resistor") {
        console.log("It is of 'string' type");
      } else {
        console.log("It is not of 'string' type");
      }

      let value;
      switch (resultString) {
        case 'Achiever':
          value = 10;
          break;
        case 'Initiator':
          value = 8;
          break;
        case 'Supporter':
          value = 6;
          break;
        case 'Follower':
          value = 4;
          break;
        case 'Resistor':
          value = 2;
          break;
        default:
          console.log('Unexpected value for response.data.body:', resultString);
          value = 0;
      }
```

I tried checking the type and using if statement. I am new to React/JS please guide. The value is correctly being returned from backend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The response.data.body is Resistor . But when it comes to switch statement its not matching

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/0tkcj5a6/).  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Perhaps the value isn't what you think it is and contains extra whitespace or even non-printable characters?

Comment: {"statusCode":200,"body":"\"Resistor\""} This is the response

Comment: Is the value `'Resistor'`?  Or is it `'"Resistor"'`?  Those are different values.  It *looks like* there are quotes surrounding the word.

Comment: I understood what's happening. It's not matching due to the quotes surrounding

Comment: I think your checking '"Resistor"'   you should check single quotes or double quotes 
like this Switch('Resistor')  or Switch("Resistor") it will be work as per excepted .